# New validation with jQuery doesn't send tha value

Tags: php, jquery, email

I want to make two verifications to Emails. 
First to verify if the email is accepted ( that it is not an incorrect mail like gimil.com homail.com ... etc) and second verification to know if email existed.

I try to do with this jQuery code

```
    $('#signup').validate({
        errorElement: 'span',
        rules:{
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
        remote: {
            url: '/verifiyEmail',
            type: 'POST', //Or whatever
        data: function(){
            return $("#email").val(); // The value of the email field
        },
        dataType: "JSON", 
        dataFilter: function(responseData){ 
            alert(responseData.message); // Or whatever
            return responseData.isValid; // validation result
        }
      }
    } 
    }
    });
```

and the PHP code

```
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $response = null;
                $isInBlackList = Member::Accepted($email);
                if($isBlackList){
                    // User is in the blacklist
                    $response = array("isValid"=>false, "message"=>"This email is blacklisted!"); // Initialize $response
                }
                else{
                    $alreadyExists = ! Member::($email); // You have to implement this.
                    if(!$alreadyExists){
                        // Email already exists
                        $response = array("isValid"=>false, "message"=>"This email is already in user"); // Initialize $response
                    }
                    else{
                        // We found a valid email
                        $response = array("isValid"=>true);
                    }
                }
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($response);
            }else{
                $response = array("isValid"=>'error');
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
```

And always the response is `error`, which means the Email is not being sent through the PHP code

Is there any solution?

Comment: You send a function in data. Php can not execute javascript functions. You need to send an actual value.

Comment: @MarkBaijens how can I do it sir ?

Comment: `data: { email: $("#email").val() }`

Comment: @PHPSA try using `console.log(responseData);` first.See the result and than try further debugging.

Comment: @NishantDongare I use the `console.log` and I found the first error ( no data sending ) the php code, email doesn't send

Comment: It's send empty ( nothing in `$_POST['email']` )

Comment: I fix this problem using GET, and make it here `url: '/verifiyEmail?Email='+$('#email).val(),` but now I want to show the error message of each one ?